# Replicating web hook

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

EDITED AS I REALISED I HAD PASTED THE WRONG CODE 
Our previous website developer created the below code to post the entries of a Gravity Form submission from our website into our CRM

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_37', 'post_to_click_dimensions', 10, 2 );
function post_to_click_dimensions( $entry, $form ) {
$cd_visitorkey = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE["cuvid"])){
    $cd_visitorkey = $_COOKIE["cuvid"];
}

$post_url = 'http://analytics-au.clickdimensions.com/forms/h/aMvdWx4ZaEUCVF6HP8XR1o';
$body = array(
    'First Name' => rgar( $entry, '1' ), 
    'Last Name' => rgar( $entry, '2' ), 
    'Email' => rgar( $entry, '3' ),
    'Organisation Name' => rgar( $entry, '4' ),
    'Phone' => rgar( $entry, '17' ),
    'Postcode' => rgar( $entry, '13' ),
    'Contact' => rgar( $entry, '6' ),
    'LID' => rgar( $entry, '10' ),
    'ReferringPage' => rgar( $entry, '14' ),
    'I am interested in' => rgar( $entry, '16' ),
    'cd_visitorkey' => $cd_visitorkey
);
```

I would like to add the same functionality for a different form that uses slightly different fields but when I replicate the above code and insert into functions.php I get a syntax error. So I tweaked the code to the below which doesn't give a syntax error but doesn't post the fields to the CRM - ant idea how to make the two codes work together??

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_48', 'post_to_click_dimensions', 10, 2 );
function post_to_click_dimensions( $entry, $form ) {

$post_url = 'http://analytics-au.clickdimensions.com/forms/h/aKyxSmgLocUuqSn5iUMvsw';
$body = array(
    'First Name' => rgar( $entry, '2' ), 
    'Last Name' => rgar( $entry, '3' ), 
    'Email' => rgar( $entry, '4' ),
    'Phone' => rgar( $entry, '5' ),
    'Postcode' => rgar( $entry, '6' ),
                    'cd_visitorkey' => $cd_visitorkey
);
```

}

Comment: Hi both your above and below codes looks similar !!

Comment: Sorry - just realised my mistake and have re-pasted the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you need to do the same functionality for different form.

For that you need to mention the form Id inside the hook as mentioned below. In the current example it will work only for the ID=>48 gform. Place your form ID in place of 'formid' in the hook call.

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_formid', 'post_to_click_dimensions', 10, 2 );
function post_to_click_dimensions( $entry, $form ) {
        $cd_visitorkey = '';
        if(isset($_COOKIE["cuvid"])){
             $cd_visitorkey = $_COOKIE["cuvid"];
        }

$post_url = 'http://analytics-au.clickdimensions.com/forms/h/aKyxSmgLocUuqSn5iUMvsw';
$body = array(
    'First Name' => rgar( $entry, '2' ), 
    'Last Name' => rgar( $entry, '3' ), 
    'Email' => rgar( $entry, '4' ),
    'Phone' => rgar( $entry, '5' ),
    'Postcode' => rgar( $entry, '6' ),
    'cd_visitorkey' => $cd_visitorkey
);
```